# How to count occurences of a certain date in a new column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns that shows a list of account numbers and the month the account opened, like below:

```
Account Month
NEW021  Oct
EVA329  Nov
VEP005  Oct
CIT410  Dec
COE210  Oct
BAR023  Jan
HOW234  Jan
```

I need to create a query to sums up the total number of accounts opened for each month. So the results should come out like this:

```
Oct 3
Nov 2
Dec 1
Jan 2
```

Comment: Have a look at [group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Answer (score 3):

```
Select Month,
count(Account) as totalcounts from table
group by Month;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the principle:

```
select [Month], count(Account) 
from t 
group by [Month];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Month,count(Account) as cntOfaccounts from tableName 
       group by Month;
```